# GuildVoiceState always returns false for inAudioChannel()

Tags: java, discord-jda

I can't figure for the life of me why the JDA doesn't return the right object for a given call.

I create the instance this way:

```
public class CatBot extends ListenerAdapter {

private static final String TOKEN = "temporary";
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CatBot.class);

public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException
{
    JDABuilder.createLight(TOKEN)
            .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES, GatewayIntent.GUILD_VOICE_STATES)
            .addEventListeners(new CatBot())
            .setActivity(Activity.playing("Here for the Sel"))
            .setStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE)
            .enableCache(CacheFlag.VOICE_STATE)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent messageEvent) {
    Message message = messageEvent.getMessage();
    User author =  message.getAuthor();
    String content = message.getContentRaw();
    Guild guild = messageEvent.getGuild();

    // avoid spam by filtering bots
    if (messageEvent.getAuthor().isBot())
        return;

    // We only want to handle messages in Guilds
    if (!messageEvent.isFromGuild()) {
        return;
    }

    // handling the case of messages that aren't in the command list
    if (!content.equals("!elcat")){
        MessageChannel channel = messageEvent.getChannel();
        channel.sendMessage("<@" + author.getId() + "> OH NO YOU'RE A DOG").queue();
    } else {
        Member member = messageEvent.getMember();
        GuildVoiceState voiceState = member.getVoiceState();
        LOGGER.info("Someone used the cat command {}", member);
            if (voiceState.inAudioChannel()) {
                AudioChannel channel = voiceState.getChannel();
                connectTo(guild, channel);
            }
        LOGGER.info("Seems like I can't get into the voice channel");
    }


}
```

When my bot receives a command, it should check if the user is in a voice channel to connect to the channel and say "hi". That should happen in the else block.
At the moment, the code stops at this line:

```
if (voiceState.inAudioChannel())
```

I tried debugging, and the voiceState object is always instantiated but the most informations are false/empty.

The doc says that to be able to use "GuildVoiceState" I need to enable "CacheFlag.VOICE_STATE" which I did, but no matter what I do, the "inAudioChannel" always returns false.
Gave the bot Admin privileges and tested it on text messages and that works.

Any idea?

Comment: How are you building your JDA instance?

Comment: I updated the code sample. I'm basically following the EchoPlayer example on the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voice state cache is directly linked to the member cache. Since you disabled all the member caching with `createLight`, the voice states attached to those members will also not be cached properly.

You need to enable voice member cache via `setMemberCachePolicy(MemberCachePolicy.VOICE)` on your JDABuilder instance.

Comment: it's indeed working, thank you. The documentation for getting the voice_state "states" that CacheFlag.VOICE_STATE needs to be enabled but doesn't mention the member cache policy, so that confused me. https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Member.html#getVoiceState()